# How to send/receive basic AT commands using Android BluetoothHeadset class?

Tags: android-bluetooth

I am developing a VOIP client and wanted to give **Bluetooth Call Control** features using AT commands. same as What **Native Phone dialer** does.

**Problem statement:**
I have a Bluetooth headset device paired and connected to Android smartphone.
I have used the  `getProfileProxy(Context, BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener, int)` as followed from 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html

Example:
To get BluetoothHeadset Proxy object,

```
 BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if ( null != mBluetoothAdapter ) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy( BizRTCContextProvider.getContext(), mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET );
            }
```

Implemented a Listener.

```
private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) { 


            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) { 
                mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy; 

            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) { 
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) { 
                mBluetoothHeadset = null; 
            } 
        } 

    };
```

Also i tried to register Vendor-specific event as below:

```
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED );
            intentFilter.addAction( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED );
            intentFilter.addAction( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED );
            intentFilter.addAction( BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT );
            //BluetoothHeadset.
            //intentFilter.
            intentFilter.addCategory( BluetoothHeadset.VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_COMPANY_ID_CATEGORY + "." + BluetoothAssignedNumbers.PLANTRONICS );
```

I am able to receive the vendor specific **AT** command inside the Broadcast receiver and can able to parse the command as below

```
    public class BTReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
            if( null == intent ) {
                return;
            }

            String action = intent.getAction();

            if ( BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT.equals( action ) ) {

                String Command = intent.getStringExtra( BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_CMD );
                int type = intent.getIntExtra( BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_VENDOR_SPECIFIC_HEADSET_EVENT_CMD_TYPE, -1 );

            }           
        }
```

The problem here is, I am not able to receive standard AT command(not vendor specific AT commands).

I wanted to send/receive Basic AT commands using **mBluetoothHeadset** Proxy object

**Example:**

I wanted to receive AT command as  **AT+BRSF=123** from headset and send response back result code as **+BRSF:219** towards headset using the BluetoothHeadset object.

I can only find the method:

```
sendVendorSpecificResultCode (BluetoothDevice device, String command, String arg)
```

This method is only limited to use **VENDOR_RESULT_CODE_COMMAND_ANDROID** as command.

Surprisingly,
I can successfully able to send and receive AT commands using **bluetoothSocket**. class as below

```
    BluetoothDevice device;
    private BluetoothSocket bthHandsfreeSocket_;
    private InputStream bthInputStream_;
    private OutputStream bthOutputStream_;
    .......
    ....
    //create socket 
    bthHandsfreeSocket_ = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( UUID );

.......
To create client connection
try{
   bthHandsfreeSocket_.connect();
}
catch( exception exp) {

}
.........
//to get the input output streams
bthInputStream_ = bthHandsfreeSocket_.getInputStream();
bthOutputStream_ = bthHandsfreeSocket_.getOutputStream();
......
....
//to read the AT commands 
bthInputStream_.read( buffer );
......

//to write the AT commands back.
bthOutputStream_.write( Commands );
```

From the Above approach, I can able to send /receive Basic AT commands.

But the problem here is

Whenever i try to route the Audio using Android AudioManager, the routing towards Bluetooth fails!!!!!

```
                audioManager_.setBluetoothScoOn( true );
                try{
                    Thread.sleep( delay );
                    audioManager_.startBluetoothSco();
                }
                catch( Exception e ){

                }
```

I even tried several modes

```
audioManager_.setMode( AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL );
audioManager_.setMode( AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION );
```

and so on...

The Audio route fails! because of this approach.

But when i use **BluetoothHeadset** class as proxy profile object.
I **do not** have any audio route issue.

But I cannot able to send and receive Basic AT commands using this proxy approach.

Any help on this will be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you combine the two approaches together?

Comment: Did you find any solution to it. Please reply

Comment: No this feature cannot be achieved in regular android phones. The bluetooth call control behavior can be achieved only in Vendor specific phones who can provide API control for bluetooth. For example the class android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadset  has lot more functions to play with. The developer site does not mention such hidden features and functions to control the call behavior.